# Get a dateTime before some hours from a specified dateTime Kotlin Android

Tags: datetime, simpledateformat, timeunit, android-dateutils, android-jodatime

I want to get a dateTime which is some hours before the specified datetime. The datetime will be in string format and depending on configuration, need a datetime n hours before the given time( example 3 or 4 hours before the given time).

The time format of mine is `2020-10-20T13:00:00-05:00`

Comment: You are sort of asking two questions in one: (1) How to parse your string into an `OffsetDateTime` (or other date-time type, but `OffsetDateTime` will be the correct, modern choice). (2) How to subtract a given number of hours from an `OffsetDateTime`. Both questions have very easy answers. Please search. (A Joda-Time `DateTime` will be a dated option but otherwise correct and easy too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "2020-10-20T13:00:00-05:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr);
        System.out.println("Given date time: " + odt);

        // 3-hours ago
        OffsetDateTime threeHoursAgo = odt.minusHours(3);
        System.out.println("Three hours ago: " + threeHoursAgo);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Given date time: 2020-10-20T13:00-05:00
Three hours ago: 2020-10-20T10:00-05:00
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using Joda-Time:**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "2020-10-20T13:00:00-05:00";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").withOffsetParsed();
        DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateTimeStr);
        System.out.println("Given date time: " + dateTime);

        // 3-hours ago
        DateTime threeHoursAgo = dateTime.minusHours(3);
        System.out.println("Three hours ago: " + threeHoursAgo);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Given date time: 2020-10-20T13:00:00.000-05:00
Three hours ago: 2020-10-20T10:00:00.000-05:00
```

**Note:** Check the following notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Using legacy API:**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateTimeStr = "2020-10-20T13:00:00-05:00";
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateTimeStr);
        System.out.println("Given date time: " + sdf.format(date));

        // 3-hours ago
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -3);
        System.out.println("Three hours ago: " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Given date time: 2020-10-20T13:00:00-05:00
Three hours ago: 2020-10-20T10:00:00-05:00
```

**Recommendation:** The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).